# Meaning of מעשה אבות סימן לבנים

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers

I have heard the phrase מעשה אבות סימן לבנים (Don't recall its source).

Does it mean:

1. The actions that our forefathers performed serve as signs for the children's actions (I.e. - we should emulate their behavior)?
2. Whatever events occurred to our forefathers serve as signs of future events that will happen to the children (us)

Can it mean both? We have seen cases in the Torah, esp. Breishit where 2 is true. For examples:

Rivka loved the youngest child, Ya'akov and Ya'akov loved the "youngest" (almost) child, Yoseph.

Ya'akovand Yosef were away from their families for many years.

Comment: Great question! I saw some nice articles about this in the *Journal of Halacha* and/or [*Tradition*](http://traditionarchive.org/archives/), and/or some other publications. I'll try to track one of those down and write up an answer, time permitting.

Comment: Needs better tagging. (+1, though.)

Comment: See [Meshech Chochma, Parshas Lech Lechah "תקבר"](http://www.sefaria.org/Meshech_Hochma,_Lekh_Lekha.33?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

Answer (score 5):

The Ramban seems to have understood it as the second option:

Ramban to Bereishis 12:6

> אומר לך כלל תבין אותו בכל הפרשיות הבאות בענין אברהם יצחק ויעקב והוא ענין גדול הזכירוהו רבותינו בדרך קצרה ואמרו (תנחומא ט) כל מה שאירע לאבות סימן לבנים ולכן יאריכו הכתובים בספור המסעות וחפירת הבארות ושאר המקרים ויחשוב החושב בהם כאלו הם דברים מיותרים אין בהם תועלת וכולם באים ללמד על העתיד כי כאשר יבוא המקרה לנביא משלשת האבות יתבונן ממנו הדבר הנגזר לבא לזרעו

My summary translation:

> Everything that happened to the Avos was a sign for their descendants, and therefore the Torah goes on at length to describe their travels and actions, which seem superfluous, which all come to teach what was going to happen in the future.

However, the Ramban then adds in another point:

> כי כל גזירת עירין כאשר תצא מכח גזירה אל פועל דמיון תהיה הגזרה מתקיימת על כל פנים
>
> When a decree is brought out from the potential decree into some symbolic action, the decree will surely come true.

The Ramban then cites examples of this from Tanach, after which he says:

> ולפיכך החזיק הקב"ה את אברהם בארץ ועשה לו דמיונות בכל העתיד להעשות בזרעו
>
> Therefore, Hashem had Avraham take hold of the Land, and did symbolic actions of all that would happen to his offspring.

The Ramban seems to imply that by Avraham modeling it, it somehow concretized its coming to fruition.

In verse 10, the Ramban is even clearer:

> והענין הזה פרשוהו בבראשית רבה (ח ו) רבי פנחס בשם רבי אושעיא אמר אמר הקב"ה לאברהם צא וכבוש את הדרך לפני בניך ואתה מוצא כל מה שכתוב באברהם כתוב בבניו
>
> This is explained in Bereishis Rabba - Rebbi Pinchas said in the name of Rebbi Oshaya: Hashem said to Avraham: Go conquer the way before your children.  And you find that everything that happened to Avraham happened to his children.